How to get connectionstring from webconfig to program.cs
I have mvc project .NET 6 to deploy on commercial Windows web hosting, not Azure, no cloud services, no containers. I try to manage access to connectionstring. I put in into webconfig file:
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RealProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
<connectionStrings>  
        <add name="MyWebconfigConnString" connectionString="Data Source=RealServer;Database=RealName;Uid=RealUser;Password=RealPsw;Encrypt=Optional; TrustServerCertificate=True;" />   
  </connectionStrings> 
</configuration>


The connection string itself works fine when accessed during development from appsettings.json. Now I want to access it from Program.cs to pass it to builder, so in production the connection string would be read from webconfig:
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyWebconfigConnString")));

and I got stucked. Simply typing its name in builder's method doesn't work. Have I omitted something important between saving data in webconfig and using it in program.cs? Or is it my "connectionstring specific" mistake while trying to access it?

It sounds like you are trying to mix a MVC web project with a console application. Non-web .NET programs use an app.config, not a web.config.

After publishing project to a server I have a web.config file in wwwroot folder. The app is running properly when using appssettings.json. Just can't figure out how to handle secure way of storing connectionstring on server.

ASP.NET Core: Where to place Connection String for Production
